# Можно ли сделать такую фигуру на CSS?

Tags: css3

Можно ли сделать такую фигуру на CSS (только одну часть)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все сделал за тебя

```css
.figure {
 margin-top: 50px;
 width: 200px;
 height: 50px;
 background: green;
 position: relative;
}

.figure::before {
 content: ''; 
    position: absolute; /* Абсолютное позиционирование */
    left: 20px; /* Положение треугольника */
    border: 10px solid transparent; /* Прозрачные границы */
    border-bottom: 20px solid green; /* Добавляем треугольник */
    transform: scaleX(10);
    left:90px;
    top:-30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="figure"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Треугольник через border + прямоугольник
https://jsfiddle.net/skywave/6g8ft03q/

html:

```
<div class="shape">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.top {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 20px solid green;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;
  border-left: 40px solid transparent;
}
.bottom {
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете так-же попробовать делать это в генераторах:

codepen.io/blazeeboy/pen/bCaLE

Или более крутая штука: http://tridiv.com/